# Java ArrayList returns error when I add element to it "UnsupportedOperationException". How to resolve this?

Tags: java

I am using Leetcode to practice algorithms. I came across Question 1218.  My code is the following

```
class Solution {
    public int longestSubsequence(int[] arr, int difference) {

        // HashMap
        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
        
        for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            if (map.containsKey(arr[i])){

                List<Integer> temp=map.get(arr[i]);
                int num = arr[i];

                temp.add(num);

                map.remove(arr[i]);
                map.put(arr[i]+difference,temp);
            } else{
                map.put(arr[i]+difference,Arrays.asList(arr[i]));
            }

        }
        int res = 1;
        for (List<Integer> i:map.values()){
            res=Math.max(res,i.size());
        }
        return res;


        
    }
}
```

The error is

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
  at line 153, java.base/java.util.AbstractList.add
  at line 111, java.base/java.util.AbstractList.add
  at line 13, Solution.longestSubsequence
  at line 54, __DriverSolution__.__helper__
  at line 87, __Driver__.main
```

P.S. Line 13 is the line `temp.add(num)`;

I am really really confused. I am just adding an integer to an array List. What I did was wrong?

Comment: `Arrays#asList` returns a fixed-size list, you cannot add nor remove from it. Note you can easily pass the contents of that into a mutable list though: `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(...));`. Note that the `#put` call with the list is unnecessary: you can modify the list retrieved from the map, and the list held in the map will also "update" (in reality, they both reference the same object).